# How to hard multiple subtitles with one command in Ubuntu FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need a command that when it is executed, you can paste the subtitles to the video files. This operation must be hard sub and include all the videos in a folder.

Example

video 1 ---- .ass1

video2------ .ass2

video3------ .ass3

With one command, hard sub all the videos above

I need a single hard sub command, I need a collective hard sub with FFmpeg

Maybe this issue can be solved with a spec script, I don't know

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "to hard subtitles". Hard is an adjective/adverb, not a verb.

Comment: The meaning of hard sub means to hack on the film and not have the ability to separate

Comment: "To hack on the film"? Sorry, looks like my English is too bad to understand you.

Comment: Hardcode subtitles on video

Comment: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/22197/ffmpeg-how-to-add-several-subtitle-streams https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo https://askubuntu.com/questions/214199/how-do-i-add-and-or-keep-subtitles-when-converting-video

Comment: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles - use si=1 si=2 si=3, etc.